# "Object not found" error within a user defined function

Tags: r, dataframe

I was trying to create a function that can perform moderate t test.

This is my function.

```
library(limma)
mod.t.test <- function(
  df.input,
  control,
  treatment
){
  
  # define comparison data frame ----
  control <- as.character(control)
  treatment <- str_split(treatment, pattern = "\\s+|\\;|\\,")[[1]]
  comparison <- data.frame(control, treatment)
  
  # perform adjust t test ----
  
  for (n in 1:nrow(comparison)){
    
    ##  Subset data for comparison ----
    dat <-  df.input %>%
      dplyr::select(starts_with(c(comparison$control[n],comparison$treatment[n])))
    
    ## design matrix ----
    
    group <- factor(c(rep(comparison$control[n],2), # in this case, each condition was performed in duplicate. If not in duplicate, need to update the numbers accordingly
                      rep(comparison$treatment[n],2)), 
                    levels = c(comparison$control[n],comparison$treatment[n]))
    
    print("print group info below")
    print(group)
    
    design.matrix <- model.matrix(~0 + group)
    row.names(design.matrix) <- colnames(dat)
    
    print("print design matrix info below")
    print(design.matrix)
    
    ## contrast matrix ----
    
    constrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(paste(colnames(design.matrix)[2], " - ", colnames(design.matrix)[1], sep = ""),
                                      levels = colnames(design.matrix))
    
    print("print constrast matrix info below")
    print(constrast.matrix)
    
    ## lm fit ----
    
    dat.fit <- lmFit(dat, design = design.matrix)
    dat.fit2 <- contrasts.fit(fit = dat.fit, contrasts = constrast.matrix)
    
    dat.fit2 <- eBayes(dat.fit2, robust = TRUE)
    
    dat.significance <- topTable(dat.fit2,
                                 coef = paste(colnames(design.matrix)[2], " - ", colnames(design.matrix)[1], sep = ""),
                                 adjust.method = "fdr",
                                 number = nrow(df),
                                 sort.by = "none",
                                 confint = TRUE) %>% 
      dplyr::select(logFC, AveExpr, `P.Value`, `adj.P.Val`)
    
    dat.significance <- dat.significance %>%
      mutate(UniprotID = rownames(dat.significance))
    
    dat.significance <- cbind(protein.meta,dat.significance)
    
    # return final data frames ----
    
    data.name <- paste("dat", paste(comparison$treatment[n],comparison$control, sep = "_vs_"), sep = "_")
    
    assign(data.name, dat.significance)}
  
}
```

When I ran this function, I got an error saying `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'design.matrix' not found`.

```
mod.t.test(df = test,
           control = "vehicle",
           treatment = "treatment1,treatment2")
```

However, the `design.matrix` was successfully created based on the following info.

```
[1] "print group info below"
[1] vehicle    vehicle    treatment1
[4] treatment1
Levels: vehicle treatment1
[1] "print design matrix info below"
              groupvehicle grouptreatment1
vehicle_r1               1               0
vehicle_r2               1               0
treatment1_r1            0               1
treatment1_r2            0               1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$group
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Does anyone know why this happened and how to solve this issue? Thanks for any help! I added the data frame I used below.

```
structure(list(vehicle_r1 = c(-2.0394795990118, -2.53062254619556, 
-2.19768074727868, -1.62718011022694, -2.67115413423132, -3.56363885921162, 
-2.74942318205691, -2.87967383936471, -4.22351468630251, -2.95885784684458, 
-3.70220173640728, -1.53399530848804, -3.9071716993092, -2.15537675455257, 
-5.16899484690255, -2.45885678632574, -2.31193284865392, -3.09552677870006, 
-2.99065940162849, -3.39327044080318), vehicle_r2 = c(-1.96959300809628, 
-2.66916130093762, -2.45230431393066, -1.62228678999365, -2.42244589013729, 
-3.51818262800615, -2.72407298861581, -2.93810773855725, -3.82352070630508, 
-2.87428456365161, -4.35614537994876, -1.36843751659403, -3.98554221778677, 
-2.97963628407393, -4.55008835321022, -2.4749825963143, -2.58964449296974, 
-2.930772440338, -2.79190897257081, -3.30289717626087), treatment1_r1 = c(2.42400111779866, 
1.81283586169609, 1.93422803579492, 2.31430877187946, 0.878696325184901, 
0.542487239774115, 1.83868969573498, 0.498941485912109, 0.891755481403184, 
1.12856745630985, 0.681349276464392, 2.47151901388531, 0.398008490791366, 
2.60712787003306, -0.253601512021707, 1.33791498108353, 1.87322596956794, 
1.41425620849447, 0.674500438903131, 0.719618534897048), treatment1_r2 = c(2.52902456386078, 
1.70961852364143, 2.01965320296157, 2.3271189557134, 0.866365670574993, 
0.642323386852482, 2.0385855605339, 0.518114600689028, 0.673576679355076, 
1.46850490871205, 0.334748820840733, 2.78935133599704, 0.446082601792636, 
0.929395261499415, 0.473521564716613, 1.70773378647496, 2.10680112419042, 
1.45935979542828, 0.744664342623103, 1.06252677829302), treatment2_r1 = c(-1.39570616029446, 
-2.09996261053952, -1.44916249149267, -1.12546243512883, -2.2549286914756, 
-2.94156546802237, -2.13740055933374, -2.31699045343704, -1.8704719940179, 
-2.44268509156176, -3.62517146354994, -0.187964138868033, -0.0799419968982562, 
-2.47635116056757, -3.95733595992217, -1.83258214296782, -1.4542656876156, 
-2.33539187393827, -2.16867014980642, -2.73429026540375), treatment2_r2 = c(-1.24532230098167, 
-1.89845977269679, -1.01283329815599, -1.01253609915911, -1.83556103040737, 
-2.82835110891965, -1.59112245047831, -2.33513343711919, -1.89535640974961, 
-1.71689550895691, -3.24605932592624, -0.0781961471575201, 0.148224445943914, 
-1.80028284151856, -3.41892674160843, -1.72491683085726, -0.859542249702738, 
-2.1865888734895, -2.00204098967698, -2.24361863886449)), row.names = c("P35580", 
"P35579", "P78527", "Q14204", "P49792", "Q93008", "Q01082", "Q14566", 
"P55072", "Q14839", "P07900", "P08670", "P33176", "P08238", "Q02790", 
"Q13813", "P05023", "P22314", "P34932", "Q9BQG0"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It took me a long time to work out the Bioc packages you're implicitly depending on here. In the future, please specify that in the question. I think you need to pass the contrast explicitly to the `contrasts` argument in `makeContrasts`, rather then to `...`. After that, you get errors in `topTable` because `df` doesn't seem to exists.

Comment: @joran Awesome. I made that change (`makeContrasts(contrasts = ...`) and the code worked now. Thanks so much! I updated my codes with the library info included. Just curious, how did you figure out where the issue is? I didn't expect adding `contrasts = ...` would make such a big difference. BTW, the code ran well without passing the contrast to the `contrasts` argument outside the `mod.t.test`. function. It seems that it only has to be passed to the `contrasts` argument inside a function.

Comment: Yes, it has to do with the use of non-standard evaluation (NSE) in the `makeContrasts()` function. Basically, arguments passed to `...` are subject to some "black magic" using functions like `substitute()` and `eval()` that assume you've literally typed in the contrasts and so it can infer column names from the expression itself, which gets complicated if you have to do a bunch of evaluation and symbol lookups to get to the eventual character representation.